# Asteroids Bullet Movement Difficulty

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I am making an Asteroids Game in HTML5 and I was stuck on the movement for the bullets at the bullets[i].move function. When I press the space bar the program draws a bullet but it just follows the ship but never moves away from the ship. You can input numbers directly into the function when calling it, but when I call the object for the speedX and SpeedY the bullets aren't moving at all. Is it the x and y position I am using for the bullets that are causing the problem? My code:

```
function Bullet(x, y, sx, sy) {

this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.sx = sx;
this.sy = sy;
this.r = 1;

this.show = function() {

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

};

this.move = function() {

    this.x += this.sx;
    this.y += this.sy;

};

this.wrap = function() {

    if (this.x > width+this.r) {

        this.x = -this.r;

    } else if (this.x < -this.r) {

        this.x = width+this.r;

    }

    if (this.y > height+this.r) {

        this.y = -this.r;

    } else if (this.y < -this.r) {

        this.y = height+this.r;

    }

};

}

for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {

    var b = bullets[i];

    bullets[i] = new Bullet(b.x, b.y, b.speedX*10, b.speedY*10);

    bullets[i].move();
    bullets[i].wrap();
    bullets[i].show();

}

if (spacePressed) {

    bullets.push({x: player.pos.x, y: player.pos.y, speedX: Math.sin(player.heading), speedY: -Math.cos(player.heading)});

};
```

Here's my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var leftPressed = false; 
var rightPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var spacePressed = false;

document.addEventListener("keydown", d); 
document.addEventListener("keyup", u);  

function d(e) { 
 
 if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
 
  leftPressed = true; 
 
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
 
   rightPressed = true; 
 
 }
 
 if (e.keyCode == 38) {
  
  upPressed = true;
  
 }
 
 if (e.keyCode == 32) {
  
  spacePressed = true;
 
 }
 
} 
 
function u(e) { 
 
 if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
 
  leftPressed = false; 
 
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
 
   rightPressed = false; 
 
  } 
 
 if (e.keyCode == 38) {
  
  upPressed = false;
 
 } 
 
 if (e.keyCode == 32) {
  
  spacePressed = false;
 
 } 
 
}

function Vector(x, y) {
 
 this.x = x || 0;
 this.y = y || 0;

}

function Bullet(x, y, sx, sy) {
 
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.sx = sx;
 this.sy = sy;
 this.r = 1;
 
 this.show = function() {
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
 };
 
 this.move = function() {
  
  this.x += this.sx;
  this.y += this.sy;
  
 };
 
 this.wrap = function() {
  
  if (this.x > width+this.r) {
   
   this.x = -this.r;
   
  } else if (this.x < -this.r) {
   
   this.x = width+this.r;
   
  }
  
  if (this.y > height+this.r) {
   
   this.y = -this.r;
   
  } else if (this.y < -this.r) {
   
   this.y = height+this.r;
   
  }
  
 };
 
}

function Player() {
 
 this.pos = new Vector(width/2, height/2);
 this.r = 15;
 this.heading = 0;
 this.facingX = 0;
 this.facingY = 0;
 
 this.show = function() {
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
  ctx.rotate(this.heading);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-this.r, this.r);
  ctx.lineTo(this.r, this.r);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -this.r);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.stroke();
  
 };
 
 this.move = function() {
  
  this.pos.x += this.facingX;
  this.pos.y += this.facingY;
  
  this.facingX *= 0.95;
  this.facingY *= 0.95;
   
 };
 
 this.applyForce = function() {
  
  var force = new Vector(Math.sin(this.heading), -Math.cos(this.heading));
  
  force.x *= 0.5;
  force.y *= 0.5;
  
  this.facingX += force.x;
  this.facingY += force.y;
  
 };
 
 this.rot = function(angle) {
  
  this.heading += angle;
  
 };
 
 this.wrap = function() {
  
  if (this.pos.x > width+this.r) {
   
   this.pos.x = -this.r;
   
  } else if (this.pos.x < -this.r) {
   
   this.pos.x = width+this.r;
   
  }
  
  if (this.pos.y > height+this.r) {
   
   this.pos.y = -this.r;
   
  } else if (this.pos.y < -this.r) {
   
   this.pos.y = height+this.r;
   
  }
  
 };

}

var player = new Player();

var bullets = [];

function draw() {
 
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
 
 for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
  
  var b = bullets[i];
  
  bullets[i] = new Bullet(b.x, b.y, b.speedX*10, b.speedY*10);
  
  bullets[i].move();
  bullets[i].wrap();
  bullets[i].show();
  
 }
 
 if (spacePressed) {
  
  bullets.push({x: player.pos.x, y: player.pos.y, speedX: Math.sin(player.heading), speedY: -Math.cos(player.heading)});
  
 };
 
 player.wrap();
 player.move(player.facingX, player.facingY);
 player.show();
 
 if (leftPressed) {
  
  player.rot(-0.1);
  
 } else if (rightPressed) {
  
  player.rot(0.1);
  
 }
 
 if (upPressed) {
  
  player.applyForce();
  
 }
 
}

function update() {
 
 draw();
 
 requestAnimationFrame(update);
 
}

update();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Asteroids </title>
  <style>
   body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="asteroids.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside the `draw` function, I put a `console.log('Here')` instruction, inside of the `if (spacePressed)` condition...it prints 7 times the message `Here` for just one space bar press....is that the expected result?

Comment: Well, for now, I just want to make the bullets move and I'm not so worried about the number of bullets now, I'll fix that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinitializing the Bullet objects each frame is where the issue was rising.

```
for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
    bullets[i].move();
    bullets[i].wrap();
    bullets[i].show();
}

if (spacePressed) {
  bullets.push(
    new Bullet(
      player.pos.x, 
      player.pos.y, 
      Math.sin(player.heading) * 10, 
      -Math.cos(player.heading) * 10
    )
  );

  spacePressed = false;
};
```

This allows the bullet object to update accordingly, you could also have done a check for the bullet's type using `instanceOf` but that would have been less readable in the long run.

The `spacePressed = false` was added to prevent multiple frames of bullets in a single press of the spacebar.

I have a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8n4mwxe0/) so you can see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

did you try moving the ship in a different direction of the bullet?
if not, try, and if bullet keeps on same path, I would suggest updating speed of bullet to be faster than ship speed